Emacs error when loading a created file into .emacs
GNU Emacs 28.2

I have created a file print2Buff.el, when starting to learn writing an emacs extension in the directory
~/.emacs.d/extensions/

In the init file, I write:
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/extensions/")
(require 'print2Buff)

Nevertheless, when the init file is opened again, it announces that, in --debug-init mode:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Loading file /home/***/.emacs.d/extensions/print2Buff.el failed to provide feature ‘print2Buff’")

How could I solve this problem?
I have striven to google many emacs file loading error but I still get stuck.
I wish I would solve the problem to start writing my own emacs extensions.

Does print2Buff.el do (provide 'print2Buff)? If not, add that.
(If it already does that, then provide more info, as the question isn't clear in that case. Provide a recipe, starting from emacs -Q.)

As already mentioned by Drew, seems like you are not "providing" the print2Buff "feature". As the last statement in your print2Buff.el, add: (provide 'print2Buff).
That should make the warning go away.
Explanation:
Require is a mechanism to load a file conditionally only once. As described in the manual, it works by pushing a "feature" (just an empty symbol), onto a list of named "features". Emacs checks if the symbol with the name of the feature is present in this list when it loads a file via the require call. If the file is already loaded, it will not be reloaded again.
Emacs also has a low-level "load" function, which unconditionally loads a library (an EmacsLisp source file) into the running Emacs process. Thus, with "load" you can re-load a file many times.
Some tips:

Use auto-insert-mode

You can enable auto-insert mode in your Emacs, by adding (auto-insert-mode +1) to your init file. With auto-insert mode on, when you create a new elisp file, Emacs will ask you if you want to auto insert the code. If you press 'y', it will automatically insert some information about you, a default license, and the provide statement, so you don't ever forget to type it.

Use optional arguments in require

You can pass an optional argument to require which tells Emacs in which file a feature resides. See the documentation string for require (C-h f require RET) for the details. This is useful so you don't need to add the directory with the file you are requiring to your load-path, for example while developing.
Additionally you can also pass in 't for the third, also optional, argument to tell Emacs to not bother with errors. That will also make the warning to away. I would say it is a bad practice though, use provide to provide the feature you are requiring instead.
